# Examples of threaded applications to test a socket library in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I've been given an open-ended project spec for a school project where I need to create both a socket library, and two unique threaded applications to test its use in C++.

Right now we're in the early stages of learning about sockets, so ideally I just want to generate some ideas for unique and moderately easy applications I could make to demonstrate a custom socket library in a Microsoft environment. I've already done quite a bit of back reading on sockets and networking theory.

The project specs are as follows:

Create a socket library for Win32/64. The library should implement the following features:

- Hide and manage the socket handle
- Fill in as many of function parameters as possible
- Automatic cleanup
- Automatic WSAStarup/Cleanup

Application Requirements:

- Client
- Server
- Apps are threaded

At this stage I don't know what the library is going to look like or how it will interact with the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a simple ftp server, and also considered a chat app. Those two applications would suffice for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from [Windows Sockets 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Getting Started with Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, take a look on tutorials like [Winsock tutorial – Socket programming in C on windows](http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/).

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I've already read up on the basics of socket programming. I'm looking for app ideas to demonstrate that knowledge, which I can then look at.